# Export image to Instagram - iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, instagram

I have an image and I want to export it to Instagram, so I can post it.

The code I'm using is:

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.igo"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];        
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savedImagePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",imageUrl);
    UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];        
    docController.delegate = self;
    docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    docController.URL = imageUrl;
    //[docController setURL:imageUrl];
    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES]; 
}
```

When I run the app, the App shows the button written "Instagram" its icon, but when I touch it, the button disappear, and nothing happens. The app didn't crash, but nothing happen.

What I missed in my code ?

Regards
Bruno

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about 'nothing happened'? When you debug it, does all that code execute and you just don't see your document interaction controller? Or is something else not working?

Comment: Carl, all code is executed and nothing happens...

the image is 612 x 612 pixels, and the NSLog shows the URL:
URL = file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/96007767-1D2E-4017-9EEA-072F3CE19452/Documents/Image.ig

Comment: Try a different first argument to `-presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:Animated:`. Perhaps try the frame of the sending button?

Comment: Did you try the UTI com.instagram.photo and .ig extension ? Are the delegate methods being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is you do not retain the `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Make an ivar for it in your class.

Make sure the method `documentInteractionController:didEndSendingToApplication:` is called on the delegate.

Also check out the Instagram documentation: http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/

> When triggered, Instagram will immediately present the user with our
>   filter screen. The image is preloaded and sized appropriately for
>   Instagram. Other than using the appropriate image format, described
>   above, our only requirement is that the image is at least 612px tall
>   and/or wide. For best results, Instagram prefers opening a JPEG that
>   is 612px by 612px square. If the image is larger, it will be resized
>   dynamically.

To verify that Instagram is installed check for the URL `instagram://app`. The URL `instagram://location?id=LOCATION_ID` is intended for location feeds only!

Comment: Phix23 it worked !
Thanks a lot !!!


I'll post here to help anyone who have the same problem.
--------------------------------------------------
in the .h
add <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;
--------------------------------------------------

Comment: Thanks Phix23 and Brunohdc.....I'm using ARC..it's not allowing me to put [docController retain]; what can i do..but if i put -fno-objc-arc in the compiler flags, it's working fine..but i want to use this in ARC..Please help me..Thanks in Advance...

Comment: @AshokKumarIOS with ARC just create an ivar or strong property for the  docController. And drop the `retain`.